# Pick day, month and year out file.lastModified();

Tags: java, android, date, last-modified

I know how to use `file.lastModified();`.
When I `println` that I get (for example): Sat Mar 17 09:24:33 GMT+01:00 2012.
But is it possible that I only get the day, month and year as numbers, for example: 17 03  2012

Is their a way to do this, maybe a filter, or an other function to get last modified date in numbers?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat class can be useful for you....

Comment: do you have a new Date(file.lastModified()) somewhere in your code? lastModified returns a long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **SimpleDateFormat** class, i.e.

```
package com.example.file;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class GetFileLastModifiedExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
    File file = new File("\\somefile.txt");

    System.out.println("Before Format : " + file.lastModified());

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    System.out.println("After Format : " + sdf.format(file.lastModified()));
    }
}
```

Comment: the return value of [lastModified](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29) is a long.

Comment: had to change   `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/YYYY");` to `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");`
After that it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

is file a java.io.File object?

lastModified should return time in milliseconds. You can create a Date object with the lastModified return value and the format the output with a SimpleDateFormat

```
    Date date = new Date(file.lastModified());
    System.out.println(date);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d M y");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
long longDate = file.lastModified();        
Date date = new Date(longDate);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String newDate = formatter.format(date);
System.out.println("Formatted date " + newDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation

> File.lastModifed()

should return a long value representing the time the file was last modified, measured in milliseconds since the epoch. Yon can use the long value in conjunction with [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)

```
    Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance()
    rightNow.setTimeInMillis(longValue)
```

and use `rightNow.get(...)`

to retrive day, month and year

Comment: or formatting it like: System.out.format("%1$td %1$tm %1$tY", rightNow);