# display files from a directory with their time stamps [last modified date] so that to move least used files to a temporary folder

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class test
{

 public static void main(String[] args)
{
  String path = "C:/stuff/";

  String files;
  File folder = new File(path);
  File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

 for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
  {
      System.out.println(listOfFiles[i].getName());
  }
}
}
```

this is my code. i want to display timestamps [last modified] details along with the file name in a sorted manner. please help..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372822/sorting-files-by-last-modified-in-java-efficient-way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
{
  System.out.println(listOfFiles[i].getName()+"\t"+new Date(listOfFiles[i].lastModified()));
}
```

Comment: it helped.also found another way to do that by using LONG variable to store lastModified() and then print it using +new Date(). anyways, both are same. THANKS :)

Answer (score 0):

[File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) Class provide function to get last modify date for that file.

You may use below code to get last modify date :

```
File file = new File("Your_File_Name");

System.out.println("Before Format : " + file.lastModified());

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

System.out.println("After Format : " + sdf.format(file.lastModified()));
```

Here is [JAVA Doc Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified()).

For sorting file list based on File Name you may refer [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898029/how-to-sort-file-names-in-ascending-order).

Answer (score 0):

About display timestamp you can do as follows:

> System.out.println(String.format("%s-%s", listOfFiles[i].getName(),
>   listOfFiles[i].lastModified()));

**listOfFiles[i].lastModified()** return the **timestamp**. If you need change it to **Date**, you can reference the link as follows:
[Pick day, month and year out file.lastModified();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818813/pick-day-month-and-year-out-file-lastmodified).

About display the filename in sorted manner, you can reference the link as follows:
[Best way to list files in Java, sorted by Date Modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203030/best-way-to-list-files-in-java-sorted-by-date-modified)